# How to extract the already present geo-tags from a folium map?

Tags: python, maps, text-extraction, folium

I want to extract the already present geo-tagged locations from the folium map. How can this be done in python?

[image]

I want to extract texts that are like the ones marked in red.
I tried saving a certain location on the map as an image and then tried extracting the text using pytesseract, but that didn't exactly work and did not seem like a long term solution, since I want to do this for the whole map of India.

Comment: please add that you tried yet.